# Compile program in same tmux window

Tags: tmux, ide

I'm new to vim and I'm trying to setup my environment for c++ development, and I want to configure vim in a way that like vscode, if I push f5 key, It would compile the program in the existing tmux pane in same window.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:make` is the standard way to compile stuff in Vim; you can map that to e.g. F5 with something like:

```
nnoremap <F5> :silent! :wa<CR>:make<CR>
```

I personally like to write all the files first; adjust according to preferences (I actually have it mapped to `MM`, which is a bit more convenient IMO).

You can call tmux from this as well, if you want:

```
:let &makeprg = "tmux send-keys -t '=myproj:=make.2' make Enter"
```

Although, arguably, using `:make` with tmux like that doesn't make too much sense, since there will never be any compiler errors to show in the quickfix window, so you can also just map it:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :!tmux send-keys -t 'myproj:make.2' make Enter<CR>
```

I'm not going to go in details on how tmux scripting works; `tmux(1)` is very useful, and I also wrote a small [Scripting tmux](https://www.arp242.net/tmux.html) article a while ago which may be of interest.

I would recommend looking in to `:make` though, since you get the quickfix window so you can easily jump to errors and the like.

Note that Vim also comes with `:terminal` now, which may be preferable over tmux panes. There are also many plugins which enhance `:make` with all sorts of things, and there probably is a tmux plugin or the like as well. This is just a simple non-automagic solution :-)

Comment: Fun facts: Dispatch has a Make command which runs the build in a separate tmux pane but correctly loads the quickfix list

Comment: Hi! That's perfect! But when I push f5 it says: error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1000/default (No such file or directory)

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: Looks like tmux isn't running yet @Aidin?